# How to count the number of child elements within an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count

**HTML**

```
<div class="fieldset_div">

<textarea name="subContext_1" class="textcountx" id="textarea__1_1">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

- I need to count the number of classes inside a class.
- I need to find the number of textareas inside the 'fieldset_div'.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Use selector for textarea with `.length` property:

```
$('.fieldset_div textarea').length
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: what does `I need to find the number of textareas inside the 'fieldset_div'.` means?

Comment: Hm, maybe I was the one that didn't read the question properly. my apologies

Comment: @Cerbrus: nevermind :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the amount of classes in a element, try this:

```
var className = document.getElementById('sidebar').className;
var count = className.trim().split(' ').length + 1;
```

To get the amount of children a certain element has, you can try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('fieldset_div')[0].childElementCount
```

However, this doesn't consider wether or not the children are text area's.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
$('.fieldset_div').find('textarea').length
```

**Demo** : http://jsbin.com/favujasivoju/1/